# WPF Program reopens by itself

Tags: c#, wpf

While opening program not from Visual Studio, but directly from the **bin\Debug\Program.exe**, the program simply closes after approx. 10 seconds and then reopens itself again (but it does not close itself again second time). This happens every single time.

I don't know why this happens, tried to check my Antivirus, but the problem was not there.

Anyone knows, what the problem is? (why it closes by itself and reopens)?

P.S. I did not try to install the program yet, as it is still raw work in progress project.

P.S.2 neither App.cs / MainWindow.cs nor any other piece of code is designed to close application (this does not occur when I run it directly from Visual Studio environment)

Comment: Is there any code in your app.xaml.cs or in your main form?  If so could you post that?

Comment: start your programm and then attach a debugger (Visual Studio) to see if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it reopens itself if it completely closed, without code to reproduce the issue, its going to be impossible to say what the problem is

Comment: I edited my post, there is no code which causes it to reopen. I don't even need to close program, it closes itself even when I don't want to

Comment: @RobertJ. I am sure that no code is designed to do that, but posting any code from those files might help since, obviously, something is going on that isn't understood.

Comment: Are you sure your app is closed? May I suggest that you use [shutdown hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718296/detect-application-shutdown-in-c-sharp-net)
and check that it was really closed?

Comment: Maybe some exception is thrown while your app is closing. Check the code for event formClosed, formClosing, etc

Comment: just to double check with you guys - I am not closing application myself, application shuts down itself without me even touching...I can simply open my **Program.exe** and it will reopen itself after 10 seconds. I am not closing anything

Comment: I also tried to debug already existing process, but no success...could not find the reason why it closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I finally figured out what the real problem was - my Antivirus program Avast! was running the app in a sandbox mode (normally it notifies when running program in a sandbox mode, however not with this one), and once it finished testing the program (after approximately 10 seconds) it unblocked the program.

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try and set [Application.ShutdownMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to explicit shutdown. Your application will then only close when you directly call Application.Shutdown.

Comment: I tried to place that in my App.Xaml.cs code, but I do not have any ApplicationExit events. Only thing that I could find was a simple **Exit** event, which however did not contain e.handled...where should I raise this?

Comment: I explored a bit further and came up with a new answer. It's a bit of a hack but it will work until you find what is causing the restart of your application

Comment: I tried Explicit shutdown, but it did not work :( application has again reopened itself in cca 10 seconds

Comment: With the current knowledge I have about the problem I have no idea as to why it's restarting itself. Could you post the source code at all?